# How to forward real .com domain to XAMPP subfolder using httpd-vhosts.conf?

Tags: server, localhost, xampp

I am trying to emulate some Google Apps app installation functionality and in order to effectively debug it, I need it running on my local Windows 7 machine (using XAMPP).

I am behind a router and I've forwarded port 80 to my local IP. When I visit my real IP in the browser I can browse the XAMPP htdocs folder, but when I visit the domain I also browse the htdocs folder. Whereas I need to browse a specific **subfolder** when I visit the domain.

I've played a bit with httpd-vhosts.conf and here's what I got right now:

```
<VirtualHost mydomain.info>
    ServerAdmin contact@mydomain.info
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/mydomain/subfolder"
    ServerName mydomain.info
    ServerAlias mydomain.info
    ErrorLog "logs/mydomain.info-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/mydomain.info-access.log" combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost localhost>
    ServerAdmin postmaster@dummy-host.localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.localhost-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.localhost-access.log" combined
</VirtualHost>
```

As you can see, the first rule should have pointed all requests to `mydomain.info` to `c:/xampp/htdocs/mydomain/subfolder`, but instead it forwards them to just `c:/xampp/htdocs`.

Edit: I forgot to mention that I use a free DNS service, to whose nameservers I have pointed the domain. Then in that service's DNS management I've added a A record for the domain with value that looks like this (IP is an example): `mydomain.info A 85.201.133.59` and TXT record, required for Google Apps verification: `mydomain.info` TXT `google-site-verification=7rgvD.....`. However, I doubt this is the problematic thing, since the domain resolves to my local machine as I have mentioned. It just doesn't resolve to the correct folder.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll find the problem is your VirtualHost declaration.

Replace:

```
<VirtualHost mydomain.info>
<VirtualHost localhost>
```

With:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

You also don't need the ServerAlias lines unless you want to direct multiple domains to the same VirtualHost

More info:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html